# 3-D graph in matlab

Tags: graph, plot

I have 3 parameters x,y,z and i would like to ask how to plot 3-D graph in matlab.

```
49.2088   18.7600   60.0000
49.2088   18.7599   65.0000
49.2089   18.7599   59.0000
49.2089   18.7600   62.0000
49.2090   18.7600   68.0000
49.2090   18.7600   65.0000
49.2090   18.7600   65.0000
49.2091   18.7600   66.0000
49.2091   18.7600   71.0000
49.2091   18.7600   78.0000
49.2092   18.7601   80.0000
49.2093   18.7601   77.0000
49.2093   18.7601   82.0000
49.2094   18.7602   80.0000
49.2093   18.7602   81.0000
49.2091   18.7605   54.0000
49.2090   18.7605   50.0000
49.2087   18.7608   66.0000
49.2087   18.7608   66.0000
49.2084   18.7611   75.0000
49.2083   18.7611   75.0000
```

The shape of graph should be like http://uloz.to/xGWT2Sz/graph-jpg

Comment: Better visit [MathWork](https://www.mathworks.in/accesslogin/index_new.jsp;jsessionid=fa1450f7944cca86d38d76bb7914) site search there or ask questios there its fully related to MatLab

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example

```
% Load the spectra data
load spectraData masscharge time spectra;

% Create the 3D plot
figure;
plot3(masscharge, time, spectra);
box on;

% Set the viewing angle and the axis limits
view(26, 42);
axis([500 900 0 22 0 4e8]);

% Add title and axis labels
xlabel('Mass/Charge (M/Z)');
ylabel('Time');
zlabel('Ion Spectra');
title('Extracted Spectra Subset');
```

**3-D looks loke**

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/35262/1/content/html/Line_Plot_3D_01.png))</sub>

for better tuto [**visit this**](https://in.mathworks.com/products/matlab/plot-gallery.html)